# Making thumbnails of images using php without reducing its quality

Tags: php, image, gallery, thumbnails

I am using the following code to make a thumbnails of an image but the quality is not up to the mark.Need help

```
   <?php
    function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width)

    {
    $source_image=imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);//width of the image.
    $height = imagesy($source_image);//height of the image.
    $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);

 imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
    $fname= basename($src); 
    $dir="upload/thumbs/";
    imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dir.$fname);

    }
    ?>
```

Thumbnails are of appropriate size but not appropriate quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do like make the image a bit larger (oversample) in size and force it smaller on output by style or what-have-you `<img style="max-width: 80%;" />`, but likely your issue is that your compression is not set on your `imagejpeg()`:

```
// This function has a quality setting (3rd value ranges from 0-100)
imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dir.$fname,100);
```

Comment: your solution worked thank you but would like to know what's the default quality value?

Comment: Adding 100 quality won't increase the shrinking quality but will increase the filesize.

Comment: The default quality is 75, according to the PHP manual, but I have found it to be too chunky

Comment: @Bhuwan default value is 75 . But you should consider resample instead of resize. Does some additional post-processing for enhancing the quality.

Comment: @AlexLinte and sometimes the quality of the compression is not good enough for the developer's taste...

Comment: file size is increased from 9 kb to 45 kb ,combining imagecopyresampled() and quality :100 gives the best result.Thank you both....alex and rascallt.both of your solution helped.....But how to maintain the file size.

Comment: try putting in a lower quality setting. Try 85. See if that is acceptable

Comment: Keep boosting it up and down to get the best value vs file size

Comment: Great! If you haven't already, maybe consider making quality a setting in your function.

Comment: I am generating thumbs for creating a gallery.Don't need it but nice suggestion.....

Answer (score 0):

You should resample the image, not just plain resize.

Use `imagecopyresampled()` like this:

```
imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
```

Comment: combining imagecopyresampled() and quality :100 gives the best result.

Comment: but the file size is increased from 9 kb to 45 kb when used 100 quality.

Comment: As commented on Rasclatt's answer, 100 q is overkill and actually removes any compression done by JPEG. With resample and a quality between 80-90 you should be ok